Combining Two Plots Side by Side in R (heatmap.2 plot)
I have two commands to generate two different plots:
plot(tree, show.tip.label = TRUE, direction = "rightwards", cex = 0.7)

and
heatmap.2(as.matrix(reordered_matrix), Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", trace = "none", key = TRUE, symm = TRUE, col = bluered(100), margins = c(5, 5))

I would like to combine these two plots so that they appear side by side in the same graph like that: 
This is what I tried:
dev.new(width = 12, height = 8)
x2 <- seq(1.9, 7.3, length.out=10)
x1 <- seq(0.2, 5.8, length.out=10)
y1 <- rnorm(10)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
par(mar=c(5,4,4,0))
plot(tree, show.tip.label = TRUE, direction = "rightwards", cex = 0.7)
par(mar=c(5,0,4,2))    
heatmap.2(as.matrix(reordered_matrix),
          Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", 
          trace = "none", key = TRUE, symm = TRUE, 
          col = bluered(100), margins = c(5, 5))

But when ploting the heatmap, the tree disappear, and the problem is from the heatmap.2 function and I didn't find something similar in the forum, because if I try to use plot() in both plots, it works and none of the answers I have found so far allow me to do that.

You should plot the heatmap first and then the tree. The graphical parameter fig lets us control the location of a figure precisely in a plot. We need to provide the coordinates in a normalized form as c(x1, x2, y1, y2).
plot.new()
par(fig = c(0.5, 1, 0, 1), new = TRUE)
gplots::heatmap.2(as.matrix(reordered_matrix), 
                  Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", 
                  trace = "none", key = TRUE, symm = TRUE, 
                  col = gplots::bluered(100), margins = c(5, 5))

par(fig = c(0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8), new = TRUE)
plot(tree, show.tip.label = TRUE, direction = "rightwards", cex = 0.7)

The heatmap is made up of the "color key and histogram" and the matrix. If you only want to plot the matrix, you must first download the graph and then crop it. In image_crop(), geometry defines the size and position of the crop. The format is "widthxheight+xoffset+yoffset".
install.packages("magick")
library(magick)

png("my_plot.png", width = 800, height = 800)
gplots::heatmap.2(as.matrix(reordered_matrix), 
          Rowv = FALSE, Colv = FALSE, dendrogram = "none", 
          trace = "none", key = TRUE, symm = TRUE, 
          col = gplots::bluered(100), margins = c(5, 5))
dev.off()

img <- image_read("my_plot.png")
cropped_img <- image_crop(img, geometry = "800x800+200+200")

plot.new()
par(fig = c(0.5, 1, 0, 1), new = TRUE)
plot(cropped_img)

par(fig = c(0, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8), new = TRUE)
plot(tree, show.tip.label = TRUE, direction = "rightwards", cex = 0.7)

